# Infinispan SingleFileStore Fragmentation issue is resolved in Infinispan version 7 or not?

Tags: caching, infinispan

I am using SingleFileStore cache, but the cache file size is keep growing it does not matter if the entries are removed from cache. after some research i have came across same issues reported

- issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-3894
- issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-3877

please append http:// before above links as it was not allowing me post question due to low reputation.

these issues are marked as fixed in infinspan version 7.0.0.Alpha4. But when i see documentation of infinispan 7.1.x for SingleFileStore here

- http://infinispan.org/docs/7.1.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_single_file_store

**Its still stating that**

In certain use cases, this cache store suffers from fragmentation: if you store larger and larger values, the space is not reused and instead the entry is appended at the end of the file. The space (now empty) is reused only if you write another entry that can fit there. Also, when you remove all entries from the cache, the file won’t shrink, and neither will be de-fragmented.

not sure if the documentation is not updated and migrating from infinispan 6.x to 7.x would help or not.

Answer (score 1):

Commits for ISPN-3894 and ISPN-3877 are in 7.1.0.Final release and later ones, so the documentation just wasn't updated when the fixes got in.